# Why can't I array_combine an array with keys with an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use `array_combine()` an array as the key `($filenames)` with two arrays as combined array objects `($tags and $cfContents)`:

```
$filenames = array();
$tags = array();
$cfContents = array();

// For loop creates three arrays based on each of the set objects
foreach( new DirectoryIterator('./cf_templates/') as $cfFile )
{
    if ( $cfFile->isDot() || !$cfFile->isFile() ) continue;
        $filenames[] = $cfFile->getBasename( '.txt' );

        $tags[] = array( "<!-- " . $cfFile->getBasename( '.txt') . " CF BEGIN -->",
                     "<!-- " . $cfFile->getBasename( '.txt') . " CF END -->" );

        $cfContents[] = file_get_contents( './cf_templates/' . $cfFile. '.txt' );

}

    // $sets = array_combine( $filenames, $tags )           // This works.
    $setContent = array_merge( $tags, $cfContents );
    $sets = array_combine( $filenames, $setContent );       // Errors on "Both parameters should have an equal number of elements"


    print_r( $sets );
```

When I run this, however, I keep getting warnings on the array $sets (see comment).  I would imagine that $setContent is merging the two arrays just fine, but the issue is with $sets??  (See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php )

Help - Why is my $sets on array_combine() not working?

Comment: It's not working because `$filenames` has a different number of elements than `$setContent`. I'm not sure how much more succinct it can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$setContent = array_merge( $tags, $cfContents );
```

create an array ($setContent) twice the size of $tags, $cfContents or $filenames. So when you call array_combine, there is not enough values in $filenames to serve as keys for the resulting array.

I think you misunderstood the behavior of array_merge. It creates a flat array that contain the values of the two arrays given in params.  Maybe I can suggest to do it this way:

```
$setContent = array($tags, $cfContents);
$sets = array_combine( $filenames, $setContent );

print_r( $sets );
```

Comment: Hi, Bar-code.  Thank you for the explanation - that is what I needed.  And thank you for the suggestion, as well.  It worked beautifully!